# Как сделать вывод слова из библиотеки в окно

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pyqt5

Нужно сделать перевод из окна1 в окно2 слов из .json файла. Код вроде работает правильно, не могу разобраться как привязать к кнопке и окнам команды действий.

Само окно [image: Окно перевода]

[Весь проект](https://dropmefiles.com/vvEjR)

```py
import json
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from perevod import *

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.btnResult.clicked.connect(self.getResult)

    def getResult(self):
        n1 = self.ui.txtNum1.text()
        n2 = self.ui.lblSum.text()

    def mbox(self, body, title='Error'):
        dialog = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, title, body)
        dialog.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Связать нужно с:

```py
from difflib import get_close_matches

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def retrive_definition(word):
    word = word.lower()

    if word in data:
        return data[word]
    elif word.title() in data:
        return data[word.title()]
    elif word.upper() in data:
        return data[word.upper()]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys())) > 0:
        action = input("Может быть Вы имели в виду %s ? [да или нет]: " % get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0])
        if action == "да":
            return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
        elif action == "Да":
            return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
        elif action == "Нет":
            return "Слово пока не существует в словаре."
        elif action == "нет":
            return "Слово пока не существует в словаре."
        else:
            return "Я не понимаю вашу запись. Извините."

word_user = input("Введите слово: ")

output = retrive_definition(word_user)

if type(output) == list:
    for item in output:
        print("-",item)
else:
    print("-",output)
```

Comment: А что за `n1`, что за `n2`? Как они должны работать с `retrive_definition`?

Comment: Это моя попытка из кода для сложения чисел методом подбора вывести для своего кода решение.По сути это "ничего"

Comment: Тогда мне непонятна суть вопроса `не могу разобраться как привязать к кнопке и окнам команды действий.` -- привязку к клику по кнопке вы и так сделали -- у вас метод `getResult` при клике будет вызываться, а дальше что вы хотите неясно

Comment: Допустим в открывшемся окне (левый столбик) пишу Худи, после нажатия на кнопку "Получить перевод" меня выбрасывает из окна. Нужно реализовать перевод в правом столбце

Comment: Можете привести пример `data.json` в сам вопрос? Не нужен весь файл, хватит несколько строк -- для нескольких слов или чего у вас там

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал функцию `retrive_definition`, чтобы она работала с диалогом, а не консолью.

И накидал [готовый пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2b623a26491507455a4583fcea7a7fdc1307864f/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5__translate__with__difflib__similar_words/main.py).

Попробуйте:

```py
import json
import sys

from difflib import get_close_matches
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QMessageBox, QLineEdit


# Для отлова исключений
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.data = json.load(open("data.json", encoding='utf-8'))

        self.input_word = QLineEdit()
        self.output_te = QTextEdit()

        self.result_pb = QPushButton('Проверить!')
        self.result_pb.clicked.connect(self._check)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.input_word)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.result_pb)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.output_te)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def _check(self):
        word_user = self.input_word.text()
        output = self._retrive_definition(word_user)

        if type(output) == list:
            output = '\n'.join(' - ' + x for x in output)
        else:
            output = ' - ' + output

        self.output_te.setPlainText(output)

    def _retrive_definition(self, word):
        word = word.lower()

        if word in self.data:
            return self.data[word]
        elif word.title() in self.data:
            return self.data[word.title()]
        elif word.upper() in self.data:
            return self.data[word.upper()]
        else:
            items = get_close_matches(word, self.data.keys())
            if items:
                text = 'Может быть Вы имели в виду "{}"?'.format(items[0])
                ok = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Вопрос', text)
                if ok == QMessageBox.Yes:
                    return self.data[items[0]]

        return "Слово пока не существует в словаре."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Создал также `data.json`:

```
{"машина": ["машины", "тачки"]}
```

---

Тестируем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если Yes:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если No:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо переписать функцию `retrive_definition` . Сделайте метод и настройте диалог, никаких `input` .

```
import json
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from perevod import *

from difflib import get_close_matches


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.btnResult.clicked.connect(self.getResult)

    def getResult(self):
        n1 = self.ui.txtNum1.toPlainText()                        # text()

        output = retrive_definition(n1)                           # <=========

        if type(output) == list:
            for item in output:
                print("-item",item)
                out = item
        else:
            print("-output",output)  
            out = output

#        n2 = self.ui.lblSum.toPlainText()                        # text()  ?
        self.ui.lblSum.setPlainText(out)                          # +++        

    def mbox(self, body, title='Error'):
        dialog = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, title, body)
        dialog.exec_()

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def retrive_definition(word):
    word = word.lower()

    if word in data:
        return data[word]
    elif word.title() in data:
        return data[word.title()]
    elif word.upper() in data:
        return data[word.upper()]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys())) > 0:
        action = input("Может быть Вы имели в виду %s ? [да или нет]: " % get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0])
        if action == "да":
            return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
        elif action == "Да":
            return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
        elif action == "Нет":
            return "Слово пока не существует в словаре."
        elif action == "нет":
            return "Слово пока не существует в словаре."
        else:
            return "Я не понимаю вашу запись. Извините."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `никаких input`, а в `retrive_definition`? :)